How to make an incomplete CSS grid row align its items to the right?
I have this very simple grid of buttons, like a telephone dial pad. The last row does not have enough items to fill it, and I want that row's items lined up to the right so that the gap is on the left. justify-content, align-content, justify-items, and align-items do not do this. Please do not tell me to set one of those properties to end unless you have a codepen showing that it works, because it does not accomplish this.
Is it even possible to do this with css grid? I'm aware I could put in an invisible "bumper" div to shunt that row over, but I'm just wondering if it's possible to control this alignment with CSS alone.
<div className="inputPanel">
        <div className="button">1</div>
        <div className="button">2</div>
        <div className="button">3</div>
        <div className="button">4</div>
        <div className="button">5</div>
        <div className="button">6</div>
        <div className="button">7</div>
        <div className="button">8</div>
        <div className="button">9</div>
        <div className="button">0</div>
        <div className="button">←</div>
      </div>

with css:
  .inputPanel {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    margin-top: 30px;

    .button {
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #d3d6da;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 2px;
      font-size: 24px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }


is the number of columns known? if it's the case, you can have a generic answer whatever the number of the items in the last row

As you know that it's the second from last element that needs to move to column 2 you can use nth-last-child(2) to position it within the grid.
The last element will then follow to the next column.


.inputPanel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  .button {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #d3d6da;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.inputPanel .button:nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
<div class="inputPanel">
  <div class="button">1</div>
  <div class="button">2</div>
  <div class="button">3</div>
  <div class="button">4</div>
  <div class="button">5</div>
  <div class="button">6</div>
  <div class="button">7</div>
  <div class="button">8</div>
  <div class="button">9</div>
  <div class="button">0</div>
  <div class="button">←</div>
</div>




I want to point out, that the CSS is now dependent on the plain HTML structure because of the use of nth-last-child. You don't style element "x", you style the whatsoever element at position "x". This is the reason why using a filler div is the better approach in this case. IMO.

Adding an otherwise unneeded element to the HTML just to achieve visual styling is I feel semantically uncomfortable. Probably not disastrous in this case but adding spurious elements can lead to accessibility complexity.

This does work for this case, and as such is sort of a valid answer, but really what I was looking for was a general solution that would control the alignment of any final incomplete row in a grid, irregardless of the exact numbers involved. So I'll upvote but I'm not going to mark it accepted.

Perhaps make it clear you need a general answer as the description of ‘like a telephone’ seemed to imply 3 columns. You’ll need a bit if JS for a completely general solution.

Based on A.Haworth answer, if you combine nth-last-child and nth-child, you can get a general solution for any number of items. For a 3 column grid, there are only 3 posibilities, and only 2 of them need an adjustment


.inputPanel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d3d6da;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(3n+1) {
  grid-column: -2;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.button:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+1) {
  grid-column: -3;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
<div class="inputPanel">
  <div class="button">1</div>
  <div class="button">2</div>
  <div class="button">3</div>
  <div class="button">4</div>
  <div class="button">5</div>
  <div class="button">6</div>
</div>
<div class="inputPanel">
  <div class="button">1</div>
  <div class="button">2</div>
  <div class="button">3</div>
  <div class="button">4</div>
  <div class="button">5</div>
  <div class="button">6</div>
  <div class="button">7</div>
</div>
<div class="inputPanel">
  <div class="button">1</div>
  <div class="button">2</div>
  <div class="button">3</div>
  <div class="button">4</div>
  <div class="button">5</div>
  <div class="button">6</div>
  <div class="button">7</div>
  <div class="button">8</div>
</div>






we have two ways to achieve this,
1. simple-> just add one empty <div></div>  in buttons 
ex: <div class="inputPanel">
        <div class="button">1</div>
        .....
        <div class="button">9</div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="button">0</div>
        <div class="button">←</div>
      </div>

2.  align them manually to end using nth-child

.inputPanel .button:nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

---->>second option will be the better aproach <<----



